# unexpected exception caught setting on, error setting expression

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

When I input the username and password in the jsp page, the data just cannot past into the code, and I got the errors below:

> unexpected exception caught setting 'password' on class action.login, error setting expression 'password' with value ['123456',]
>
> unexpected exception caught setting 'username' on class action.login, error setting expression 'username' with value ['test',]

login.jsp:

```
<body>
    <s:form action="login" method="post">
        <s:textfield label="username" name="username"/>
        <s:password label="password" name="password"/>
        <s:submit value="submit"/>
    </s:form>
</body>
```

This is my action class:
**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>, Preparable {
    /**
     * 123
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2484039811971165080L;
    private IUserService userService=null;
    private String id;
    private int pageIndex=1;
    private String pageBar;
    private List<User> list_t;
    private User user;
    
    public void prepare()throws Exception{
        System.out.println("--prepare--");
        System.out.println(id);
        if(id==null||id.length()==0){
            user=new User();
        }else{
            user=getUserService().getUserById(Integer.parseInt(id));
        }
    }
    public String execute()throws Exception{
        System.out.println("--execute--");
        System.out.println(user.getId());
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        if(getUserService().isLogin(user)){
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return INPUT;
    }
    public String save()throws Exception{
        if(getUserService().insertUser(user)){
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;
    }
    public String edit(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String update()throws Exception{
        if(getUserService().updateUser(user)){
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;
    }
    public String delete()throws Exception{
        if(getUserService().deleteUser(Integer.parseInt(id))){
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;
    }
    public String findAllUser()throws Exception{
        try {
            System.out.println("findAllUser");
            list_t=getUserService().getAllUser();
            ServletActionContext.getRequest().setAttribute("list", list_t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPageIndex() {
        return pageIndex;
    }

    public void setPageIndex(int pageIndex) {
        this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    }

    public String getPageBar() {
        return pageBar;
    }

    public void setPageBar(String pageBar) {
        this.pageBar = pageBar;
    }

    public List<User> getList() {
        return list_t;
    }

    public void setList(List<User> list) {
        this.list_t = list;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    public IUserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }
    public User getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return user;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "data just cannot past into the code"?

Comment: The code cannot get the 'username' and 'password' I input.

Comment: Don't use modeldriven unless you know what are you doing.

Comment: Use `ParameterAware` to get the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

The problem is that in your action you don't have declared the field "password" like:

```
private String username; //{add getters&setters too}
private String password; //{add getters&setters too}
```

Regards :)